# Different outgoing IP based on the IP the client connected to via squid?

Tags: linux, proxy, debian, squid

I got a Linux server (Debian) with 5 IPv4 addresses running **Squid** and the server can be reached from any of those 5 IP addresses.
**I would like to make Squid route to a different outgoing IP based on the IP that the client connected to.**

Example:
Client connects to *xx.xxx.xxx.26* I would like the outgoing IP to be *xx.xxx.xxx.26*.

Client connects to *xx.xxx.xxx.27* I would like the outgoing IP to be *xx.xxx.xxx.27*.

**I would also like to limit the access to the proxy to only allow connections from a certain IP.**

Is this possible and how would I implement such a feature?

*I've managed to route different ports to different outgoing IP-addresses, but this is not optimal for my situation.*

Comment: Updated the question to be in compliance with the guidelines.